# Python basic: if i use open() and read() at once like open().read() then close() is called automatically?

Tags: python, io

Case 1)

```py
f = open(file.txt, 'r')
content = f.read()
f.close()
```

Case 2)

```py
content = open(file.txt, 'r').read()
```

Does case 1 and 2 work exactly the same? Even without a close?

I want to avoid the trouble of using the `close` method when I open the file.
Of course, I don't want to use the `with`.

Comment: Why don't you want to do this with `with`? That feature is designed for avoiding `close`.

Comment: If you don’t call `close` explicitly it’ll happen at some point on its own, but exactly when is not always obvious so it’s much better to be explicit.  Why do you “of course” not want to use `with`?

Comment: “Of course”, you should use `with`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just don't want to use with because I am lazy